# How to change multiple id color using input in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, telnet

I have a webpage that I want to manipulated remotely or by touch screen when input mute or muteon text. This is the current code I have where if call togglemute() muteon will turn red, and if mute will change to green. I want to know how would I incorporate this with the html code I want manipulated at the bottom so that id="text" and id="text1" change colors when text mute or muteon text is inputted. Please advise. Thanks!

HTML:

```html
<div class="mute-container">
    <div class="mute-on">Mute On</div>
    <div class="mute-off">Mute Off</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```js
function toggleMute() {
    document.querySelector('.mute-container').classList.toggle('on');
}
```

CSS:

```css
.mute-container.on .mute-on {
    color: red;
}

.mute-container:not(.on) .mute-off {
    color: green;
}
```

HTML want Manipulated/Incorporated:

```html
<h1 class="l1-txt1 txt-center p-t-0 p-b-10">
    <p id="text1" style="color:white; font-weight: 600"></p>
</h1>

<h1 class="l1-txt1 txt-center p-t-0 p-b-60">
    <p id="text" style="color:crimson; font-weight: 600"></p>
</h1>
```

Comment: where would you like which parts exactly to be 'placed' in the end - e.g., only the inner HTML (the text "Mute On/Off") or the whole container? to put it differently: what do you want your final HTML-result to look like?

Comment: I would like the final html to only show id="text" and "text1". I have two webpages so on the other webpage which is my customization page I would like for the option to input mute or muteon in a textbook to change "text" and "text1" color to red or green @m1ck

Comment: so, if what you want is for the above style + style changes to be applied to the elements in the code below (of id="text" and "text1"), you can either a) give them the according class names (depending on what you want to be red and green), or b) add the ids of the elements to the rules next to the classes.

Comment: How would I do that, I am still fairly new to programming and html @m1ck

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, you want `text1` to correspond to the behavior of `mute-on`, i.e. turn `red` when toggled on, and `text` to behave like `mute-off`, i.e. become `green` when toggled on (switch that if necessary). I'll also assume that you want the toggled-off-color for `text1` to be `white`, and for `text` to be `crimson`, as per your inline CSS.

Then here's an easy way to do this:

a) Add a container element around your HTML code below, and give it the class `mute-container`. Like this:

```
<div class="mute-container">

    <h1 class="l1-txt1 txt-center p-t-0 p-b-10">
        <p id="text1" style="color:white; font-weight: 600"></p>
    </h1>

    <h1 class="l1-txt1 txt-center p-t-0 p-b-60">
        <p id="text" style="color:crimson; font-weight: 600"></p>
    </h1>

</div>
```

b) Add the classes `mute-on` and `mute-off` to the elements with id `text1` and `text`:

```
<div class="mute-container">

    <h1 class="l1-txt1 txt-center p-t-0 p-b-10">
        <p id="text1" class="mute-on" style="color:white; font-weight: 600"></p>
    </h1>

    <h1 class="l1-txt1 txt-center p-t-0 p-b-60">
        <p id="text" class="mute-off" style="color:crimson; font-weight: 600"></p>
    </h1>

</div>
```

c) Finally, in order for the default-color defined inline (`white` and `crimson`) to not override the toggled-on-colors (`red` and `green`), either

- add `!important;` to you non-inline CSS rules:

  ```
  .mute-container.on .mute-on {
      color: red !important;
  }

  .mute-container:not(.on) .mute-off {
      color: green !important;
  }
  ```

or

- move the inline CSS for the default-colors into your non-inline CSS (and delete them inline):

  ```
  .mute-container .mute-on { /* text1 - will turn red when toggled on */
      color: white;
  }

  .mute-container .mute-off { /* text - will turn green when toggled on */
      color: crimson; 
  }
  ```

Hope this helps!